# Show macros in debug symbols (embedded)

Tags: c, debugging, macros, embedded

I am working with embedded application, and during debugging, the debugger is not able to resolve macro symbols (my theory: because macros are lost in preprocessing). I end up having to find the macro in source code first and then use the definition to watch a variable.

My question is:
Is there a way to incorporate the macro definition inside by elf file?
If yes, what steps do I need (flag do i need to set during compile, for example)?
If no, why not?

Any info is appreciated.
My exact setup is WindRiver compiler and lauterbach debugger.
But if you have info about other environment, please share, perhaps I can find a counterpart for my environment.

Comment: That's the main reason macros should be avoided (i.e., they are not easy to debug).

Comment: With `gcc` compile with `-g3` to embed a macro, then use `info macro` with `gdb`.

Comment: Consider using enumeration constants and/or constant objects instead of macros.  See [this article](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/programming-pointers/4023879/Enumeration-Constants-vs-Constant-Objects) for details.

Comment: @kkrambo, I would if I could.

Comment: @ouah thank you. this is the kind of info I am looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how this translates to your compiler & debugger, [but it's possible with GCC and GDB](https://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/entry/8_gdb_tricks_you_should).

If you rebuild and tell GCC to generate debug symbols optimized for GDB, using `-ggdb3`, it can preserve macro information:

```
$ make KCFLAGS=-ggdb3
...
(gdb) info macro task_is_stopped_or_traced
Defined at include/linux/sched.h:218
  included at include/linux/nmi.h:7
  included at kernel/sched.c:31
#define task_is_stopped_or_traced(task) ((task->state & (__TASK_STOPPED | __TASK_TRACED)) != 0)

(gdb) macro expand task_is_stopped_or_traced(init_task)
expands to: ((init_task->state & (4 | 8)) != 0)

(gdb) p task_is_stopped_or_traced(init_task)
$2 = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, macros do not appear in debugging symbols because of how C files are compiled.

First, the file is preprocessed, and macros are expanded. Then, all preprocessing directives are deleted, and macro definitions discarded. Next, the actual compiling to machine code takes place, and this is where the compiler builds debugging information.